# Is there a way to send only relevant data when a form has multiple similar fields?

Tags: php

I'm trying to recreate a "commentary section" on my project. I have a loop to display many "posts" and each post has it's own comment section, all inside the same Form. because of that I end up having multiple fields with similar names (i.e button1, button2, button3, etc etc etc, one for each post). Is it possible to have one isset($post['button']) that fits all and only brings the info related to the one I clicked?

I could have each post be a separate Form but then I would have do re-do a good portion of what I did so far. I was hoping there's a way around it

that's what I have:

```
input type='text' name='post_comment".$k."' class='form-control' value=''
input type='submit' class='btn' name='postComment".$k."' value='Comment'


...


if(isset($post['postComment'])){
   //do something
}
```

If I hardcode $k into my isset (i.e isset($post['postComment34'])) everything works as I wanted. Is it possible to have my isset accept any 'postCommentxx'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to use an array with matching indexes:

```
<input type='text' name='post_comment[$k]' . . . 
<input type='submit' name='postComment[$k]' . . .
```

Then you can use the index of the submit to get the text:

```
if(isset($post['postComment'])){
    $key  = key($_POST['postComment']);
    $text = $_POST['post_comment'][$key];
}
```

I would change `postComment` to something like `submit` as it is confusing to have variables of the same name just slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

So, if I understand your question right, you want to just use 1 form and not using multiple forms for sending comments on posts. Try using `<button type='submit'>` instead of `<input type='submit>'`. Look at my example:

```
<input type='text' name='post_comment".$k."' class='form-control' value=''>
<button type='submit' class='btn' name='postComment' value='".$k."'>Comment</button>
```

Now you can go on with your php code;

```
if (isset($_POST['postComment'])) {
    $postid = $_POST['postComment'];
    $comment = $_POST['post_comment'.$postid];
    // Do something
}
```

That's it! (I hope I helped you :P)

Comment: @AbraCadaver It won't because you use `<button>` and not `<input>` ;)

Comment: This is actually a good solution for what they already have, though what they already have is not great.